# Apache Nifi Concurrency java explanation

Tags: java, concurrency, apache-nifi

I have created custom processor in java.i have basic understanding how the processor works but still i have no idea about how the nifi scheduling uses concurrent Tasks.

[image: sample concurrent task of a processor.]
Here,i have used 10 concurrent tasks but i dont have the clarity on how these concurrent tasks are programmed in java.

I understand nifi uses concurrency framework but still i dont know how it will be implemented while creating custom processor.

Please give some brief explanation with code samples.

Answer (score 2):

Concurrent Tasks refers to how many threads will be allotted to the processor to run the `onTrigger` task concurrently, allowing you to process multiple FlowFiles at the same time. The processor is initialized once when it is scheduled, but then `onTrigger` is called from each task. This means any variables you use in `onTrigger` need to be thread-safe so the tasks are not updating the same variable(s) at the same time. Usually this means you'd create most variables inside `onTrigger` and any shared variables are set up during the `@OnScheduled` method so they are not updated concurrently. Any variables that need to be updated by each task should use synchronized code and structures such as `AtomicReference`, but even so take care to make sure one task's update is not overwritten by other tasks.

There is a [section in the User Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#concurrent-tasks) that provides more information.